# Twitter API returning "Could not authenticate you."

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I try to get an access token but it does not seem possible. Right now I have this:

The url used

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fd5c7-31-20-39-126.ngrok.io
```

The headers:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="REMOVED", oauth_nonce="nGyTdMEgFmkMNOJYOLOBkGiHZPYAwDkg", oauth_signature="oauth_signature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1637605635", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Than the response is:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

I think something is wrong with the `oauth_signature`. The [twitter api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/api-reference/request_token) shows that it needs to me `oauth_signature` but even when I encode it with HMAC-SHA1 I get the same error. Should I encode something else for the signature?

I also used this guide but cannot get past step one [twitter guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens).

Comment: I have the same problem, and the same URL composition, and headers, how did you fixed it? Thank you

Comment: @MarGraz I did not manage to fix it

Comment: In .Net I fixed it using an external library to manage the OAuth. This library is called OAuth.DotNetCore v. 3.0.1, here the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/rhargreaves/oauth-dotnetcore), and here the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.DotNetCore)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work for 127.0.0.1 (localhost) with Node.js, here's what I've done:

1. Use openssl to generate cert and key files:
   `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -keyout example.key -out example.crt -subj "/CN=example.com"  -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.net,IP:127.0.0.1"`
2. Add the certificate to trusted root authority -> browser settings, import certificate
3. check https://127.0.0.1:port , the certificate should be green now
4. In your index.js use:
   `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';`
5. Add to twitter developer portal your callback url, as an example: https://127.0.0.1:3000/callback.html
6. From the https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token request remove the body with the callback. It should post without any callback (idk why because docs are saying that you must pass the callback in the POST request_token body)

If everything went ok you should be able to communicate to Twitter API from your local machine.